# How to filter captured packages?

Tags: wireshark

I would like to filter packages in Wireshark before capturing them. I want to capture only packages of `DIS` protocol. I can filter displayed, already captured packages, but it makes my pc unusable.

Comment: Use a capture filter.

Comment: :) I don't know how to write the filter. Just `DIS` doesn't work.

Comment: Try ´dis` instead of `DIS`.

Answer (score 2):

I have observed that, running TShark is less CPU intensive than the Wireshark GUI. Use tshark instead of Wireshark. TShark is a terminal oriented version of Wireshark.

Syntax : -j “protocol match filter”

Example: tshark -j "ip ip.flags http"

For Tshark, Refer link : https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html

For Dis protocol filters, refer link : https://www.wireshark.org/docs/dfref///d/dis.html

Comment: On tshark I preffer using -Y instead of -j. I add any filter like this: sudo tshark -i <My_Interface> -Y '(ip.addr == <My_IP> and DIS)'

Answer (score 0):

`Wireshark` by default does not support every protocols on its filters. If you write just `ssh` or `http` or other very common protocol, then `wireshark` will filter only packets from that protocol, but for some protocols you'll need to add some plugins.

On the current version of `wireshark` you have the filter `dis`, notice the protocols should be written in `lowercase`.

From the filter bar you can add complex filters by combining conditions using logic and relational operators like `and`, `or`, `!` and `==`.

A better approach would be using the `wireshark` comand line, i.e. `tshark` which you most likely will need to install after `wireshark`.

On `tshark` you have the `-i` option to indicate the interface to sniff and the `-j` option to indicate the filters, but I prefer the `-Y` option which allows more filters and this is what you need, something like this:

```
 sudo tshark -i <Your_Interface> -Y '(ip.addr == <My_IP> and DIS)'
```